# Apache / PHP / php-fpm: locale settings change themselves

Tags: php, apache

I experienced a bug with Apache and php-fpm: locale settings change themselves randomly.

Here are the correct locale settings:

```
Array
(
    [decimal_point] => .
    [thousands_sep] => 
    [int_curr_symbol] => 
    [currency_symbol] => 
    [mon_decimal_point] => 
    [mon_thousands_sep] => 
    [positive_sign] => 
    [negative_sign] => 
    [int_frac_digits] => 127
    [frac_digits] => 127
    [p_cs_precedes] => 127
    [p_sep_by_space] => 127
    [n_cs_precedes] => 127
    [n_sep_by_space] => 127
    [p_sign_posn] => 127
    [n_sign_posn] => 127
    [grouping] => Array
        (
        )

    [mon_grouping] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

And here are the changed settings:

```
Array
(
    [decimal_point] => ,
    [thousands_sep] =>  
    [int_curr_symbol] => EUR 
    [currency_symbol] => €
    [mon_decimal_point] => ,
    [mon_thousands_sep] =>  
    [positive_sign] => 
    [negative_sign] => -
    [int_frac_digits] => 2
    [frac_digits] => 2
    [p_cs_precedes] => 0
    [p_sep_by_space] => 1
    [n_cs_precedes] => 0
    [n_sep_by_space] => 1
    [p_sign_posn] => 1
    [n_sign_posn] => 1
    [grouping] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

    [mon_grouping] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

)
```

The problem occurs randomly and I think it is due to processes, like it is said on [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php#refsect1-function.setlocale-notes):

> The locale information is maintained per process, not per thread. If you are running PHP on a multithreaded server API like IIS, HHVM or Apache on Windows, you may experience sudden changes in locale settings while a script is running, though the script itself never called setlocale(). This happens due to other scripts running in different threads of the same process at the same time, changing the process-wide locale using setlocale().

When removing php-fpm and using FastCGI, the problem doesn't occur anymore. How can I get this working with php-fpm? The problem occurs on a shared hosting (we are the company which provides the hosting) and we really need php-fpm in order to use pools.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about apache, but Nginx has a configuration variable to set the worker threads. Configuring apache to run one thread at a time might solve your problem, but of course it may not be desired performance wise.